# Getting an error with GET from HTTP server in Java

Tags: java, http, get, keytool

I was working on a project for a school where it swaps out the school bell every week.
I made a java app that gets every 10 mins from an http server a song. It works perfectly when on my own network, but when I use my school's network it seems to block it (netspark firewall) the oddest part is that it only started blocking it after a few days.
The error I'm getting is (`"Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"`) I've seen around that I need to add some sort of keystore file, but can't get that to add properely.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The "after a few days" bit may be due to certificate caching.

Comment: Hmmm, any idea to get it so it likes my certificate?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what library you are using to make GET requests. Some libs like Unirest has verifySsl(false) option to skip certificate validation

Comment: I'm just using the default java httpUrlConnection class. No external libs